# extend the parameters for sharepoint 2010 advanced serch

Tags: 2010, search, advanced-search

I am using the advanced search box web-part for SharePoint 2010.

In that it provides 5 additional filters in the " Add Property restrictions " section as highlighted in the screenshot below. Is there any way by which I can extend it to allow 10?

[image]

Thank You.